# Streamfield UI missing on edit page after upgrade to Wagtail 2.0.2

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

after upgrading one of our Wagtail sites to Wagtail 2.0.2, Django 2.0.13, Python 3 we've found some pages when editing don't display the Streamfield part, in the source there is just an empty UL element. There's no Javascript console or server error, so I'm a bit lost how to debug, or work out why it's happening on just some pages. Has anyone experienced this? Thanks

Comment: Getting an error running locally 'li element found outside of an enclosing list element' /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wagtail/admin/rich_text/converters/html_to_contentstate.py in create_block, line 120

Comment: And on another page with a missing SF section 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Thinking now it's this issue https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4602